# How to touch the same object from 2 lists... (References)

Tags: c#, list, class, reference

I have problem, I wanna make 2 or 3 lists of objects of my own class, but wanna be sure that some of object can be in more lists. So I wanna have 2 lists of objects with attributes (objects are instances of the same class MyClass)
But I wanna be sure that if I will edit some attributes in object1, and when I will open ListB, I wanna be sure that, that attributes from that edit will be avaible from listB. I am not sure how it will be with references. C#
Do you have some solution??? thanks

For example:

**ListA:**

- object1
- object2
- object3
- object4

**ListB:**

- object5
- object6
- object1

Comment: As long as they are classes, it will work as you say. For structs, its another story.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a copy of object1 in both listA and listB it won't matter where you edit it since it's the same instance.